# Array of classes, subclasses of specific class

Tags: java, android, arrays, class, generics

I have got an array of Classes, declared as follows:

```
Class<?>[] serviceStack = {GetPlanningData.class, GetTimeTable.class, GetDataToSync.class, GetData.class};
```

Classes `GetPlanningData`, `GetTimeTable`, `GetDataToSync` and `GetData` are all subclasses of `IntentService`.

Can I declare an array of subclasses of `IntentService`? I tried:

```
Class<? extends IntentService>[] serviceStack;
```

and

```
Class<IntentService>[] serviceStack;
```

but the first one is a "Generic array creation", as Android Studio says, and the second one permits only to create `{IntentService.class, IntentService.class, ...}` and no subclasses are allowed.

EDIT: I am programming in Android, and the main goal of this is to call Services sequantially. So I put this array as an extra of the first Service and when the service has finished I call the first element of the array, passing the array without the first element.

This works, but I can't use Lists because I can't put a List extra to a Context.

Comment: I would work around the issue and create a generic collection instead. Something in the lines of `List<? extends IntentService>`.

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: I have to call a series of `IntentService` sequentially, but I can't use a List (that'd be great) because, programming on Android, I can't put a List "extra".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use array. Create a `List` instead:

```
List<Class<? extends IntentService>> serviceStack = Arrays.asList(
    GetPlanningData.class, GetTimeTable.class, 
    GetDataToSync.class, GetData.class);
```

This way you will be type-safe.

Comment: That would be great, but I can't use Collections, because programming on Android I have to put this array in an extra, and I can't put a list in a extra.

Answer (score 2):

I think this answers your question:

**You cannot create arrays of parameterized types**

source:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays

Comment: That is unfortunately not strictly true: to be precise you cannot directly instantiate arrays of non-reifiable types. You can therefore instantiate an array like `new Foo<?>[1]` as it is reifiable (the only reifiable parameterized type is an unbounded wildcard parameterized type).